# axway titanium 6.3.0.GA error building for android

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

i tried to build the classic multi-tab template app for android on titanium `6.3.0GA` and i am getting the below error.
there is no error building this with ti `6.1.0GA`. can you point me in the right direction? thx. (btw. i'm. on node `v8.2.1` as recommended by titanium)

```
[INFO] :   Building Java source files: [...]
2017-11-16T13:04:50.362Z | ERROR  | An uncaught exception was thrown!
Path must be a string. Received null
2017-11-16T13:04:50.363Z | ERROR  | Path must be a string. Received null
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

Comment: have you tried lowering the log level to see if you see anything else? And what is your CLI version?

Comment: Use Trace level in Console while building the app, it will show you more info on file causing this error. Somewhere in some file, you are not passing any value for a String value as Path.